# Redundancy in Android Model-View-Presenter between Model and View Adapter

Tags: android

If we look at Google's Android Architecture example for Model-View-Presenter (MVP), particularly these two lines:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksFragment.java#L357

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/source/TasksRepository.java#L50

We see the collection of Tasks is redundant - one is stored in the model in a Map, and one is stored in the View's Adapter as a List.

Is this a necessity?  Is it possible for the list to be stored once, or must we always be duplicating the list between the Model and the View's Adapter?  If it only had to be stored in one place, obviously that would be in the Model/repository portion.

Most importantly, if it is not a necessity to duplicate the objects list, how would the implementation work to not duplicate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not the given example uses it, I can create a collection in the model's repository, and then access that collection by a reference to the collection from the View Fragment's Adapter.  Thus no duplication is needed - the collection is in the model's repository, the reference to the collection outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently facing the same problem too.  My approach is the a ame as you, I. E. Store a reference of the lia in the adapter instead of using a new reference,  since it is easily to do modification on the list if needed. One point to note is that not to modify the list in another thread,  or modify the list without notifydatasetchanged .